# Call current date&time into dynamic variable in Powershell

Tags: powershell, script

I need to create some logs that contain the current time
I don't want to repeatedly call the Get-Date cmdlet
How can I simply set a dynamic variable?

I've tried this:

```
$CurrentTime=(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss:ffff"::Now)
<# Some code #>
Write-host $CurrentTime::Now "int result 1"
<# Some code #>
Write-host $CurrentTime::Now "int result 2"
<# Some code #>
Write-host $CurrentTime::Now "int result 3"
```

But the output has the wrong format.

```
24.10.2022 18:53:35 int result 1
24.10.2022 18:53:35 int result 2
24.10.2022 18:53:35 int result 3
```

How would I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I found answer how do it with function:

```
    function CurrentTime
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [string]$CurrentTime
    )

    Write-Output ("{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss:ffff"), $CurrentTime)
}

Write-host | CurrentTime "int result 1"
<# Some code #>
Write-host | CurrentTime "int result 2"
<# Some code #>
Write-host | CurrentTime "int result 3"
```

Result output:

```
2022-10-24_22:15:21:4042 - int result 1

2022-10-24_22:15:21:4052 - int result 2

2022-10-24_22:15:21:4062 - int result 3
```

Comment: For extra simple, these two line examples alone should do it too: `Function CurrentTime {(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss:ffff")};
Write-Host "$(CurrentTime) int result 1";`

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle, thx a lot. It's heplful

Answer (score 1):

Creating a dynamic Variable

```
$Global:CurrentTime = Set-PSBreakpoint -Variable CurrentTime -Mode Read -Action {  Set-Variable CurrentTime (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss:ffff") -Option ReadOnly, AllScope -Scope Global -Force }

Write-host $CurrentTime "int result 1"
```

Result

```
2022-10-26_00:17:09:8975 int result 1
```